# deleting an item from array and add it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to delete an item from an array and add it to another array. The array states consists of a list of 50 states. User needs to enter the name of a state and the state must get deleted from states array and get added to the array correctState. Here is my code

```
function searchString()
{
    var total = 50;
    var string = document.getElementById("txtState").value;
    var element = document.getElementById("status");
    for (i=0; i < states.length; i++)
    {
        if(states[i].toUpperCase() == string.toUpperCase())
        {
            count = count + 1;
            //element.innerHTML = "CORRECT!!!"
            addElem = states.splice(i,1);
            correctState.push(addElem);

            /*for (j=0; j < correctState.length; j++)
            {
                if(correctState[j].toUpperCase() == string.toUpperCase())
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Already Submitted. Try another State";
                }
            }*/
        }
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = count +"/"+ total;
        document.write(states);
        document.write(correctState);
    }
}
Enter State : <input type="text" name="txtState" id="txtState"><span id="timer"></span><br /><span id="status"></span>
<button type="button" name="btnPlay" id="btnPlay" accesskey="s" onClick="searchString()"><u>S</u>ubmit</button>
```

I'm not able to achieve what I need. I'm new to javascript and need help.

Comment: In order to help you, we have to know what's not working. You kinda forgot to mention that.

Comment: Where did you initialize the states array ?

Comment: I'm trying to delete an element from states and add it to correctState

Comment: Usually you would also explain what you want it to do and what it is doing instead. Ideally you should set up a jsfiddle so people can play around with it and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: oh also, `document.write` is not a good way to debug anything. You should pretty much never use it. Use `console.log` instead and just look at your browser's console. As a matter of fact, in the typical workflow you will always have your console open and use it for experimenting and prototyping many times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Re these lines:

```
addElem = states.splice(i,1);
correctState.push(addElem);
```

`splice` doesn't return the *element* that you remove, it returns an *array* of those elements. So your code is pushing array instances onto `correctState`. I'd do this:

```
correctState.push(states[i]); // First push the matching state onto `correctStates`
states.splice(i,1);           // ...then remove it
```

Alternately, you *could* do it in the order you showed, you just have to get the removed element out of the array you get back

```
addElem = states.splice(i,1);
correctState.push(addElem[0]);
// Here -----------------^^^
```

but again, I'd do it by pushing first, then removing.

---

Separately, I'd use the debugger built into your browser to single-step through that code and watch it run. I suspect you'll find that you want to move some things around, and you almost certainly want to stop looping once you've found that `string` matches something in the array.

Comment: This still doesn't address the mutation-and-enumeration issue in my post but will work fine if the lists contain unique values

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Indeed (see the final paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the fact that you're modifying your `states` array while you are still enumerating.

So say you're states array is `[AR, LA, CT]` and the user entered `LA`. So your for loop goes like this

```
i = 0 (length is 3 so i < 3)
string not found
i = 1 (length is 3 so i < 3)
string found, remove it from states
i = 2 (length is 2 so i < 2 fails and there's no final loop)
```

What you probably want is just something like this

```
function moveAllInstancesBetweenArrays(val, source, destination) {
    var indexOfVal = source.map(function(s) { return s.toUpperCase() })
                           .indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
    if(indexOfVal == -1)
       return;
   source.splice(indexOfVal, 1);
   destination.push(val);
   moveAllInstancesBetweenArrays(val, source, destination); //continue until all matching are moved
}

moveAllInstancesBetweenArrays(yourSearchVal, states, correctStates);
```

Comment: Your guess seems right, you should show how to fix it.

Comment: Working on it...got to write up an explanation first

Comment: @Barmar: I don't see how, the limit on the loop is `states.length` and the code doesn't rely on `i` after the `splice`.

Comment: *"...string found, remove it from states / length is 2 so i < 2 fails and there's no final loop..."* But `string` can only match one entry *anyway*, so... It would be an issue if `string` could match multiple entries, no question, but it's not relevant here.

Comment: The problem with iterations like this is with `i++` in the `for()` loop. After you splice out the current element, the next element moves into its place. But the next iteration moves past it, so you never process that element. The simplest solution to this problem is to iterate down instead of up.

Comment: Although if the array elements are known to be unique, as they probably are in this example, you can simply `break` out of the loop after splicing it out, and there's no problem with the rest of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar not sure where you got that from my answer, I actually don't do an explicit loop at all and leave subsequent splicing to recursion. Not really the most preformant solution, but should preform fine for the OPs use case no problem.

Comment: I think I wrote my original comment when the only thing in your answer was the first line, before you added the `source.map` code.